# Three js application crashes when loading a lot of 4k textures

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl2

I use three js, load textures and models from the server, immediately assemble meshes and render, the fact is that when there are a lot of my 4k textures, the page simply reloads without any error (on the iphone)

Comment: Your CPU isn't great on a phone - most people's aren't. If WebGL can't handle something, it will crash. You should consider compressing your textures, but it might work better on computers.

Comment: That sounds like an out-of-memory crash, which makes sense. The only answer is probably: use less memory.